# DB migrations in container

Tags: docker

Given a service stack consisting of a

- Application (flask)
- Database (mysql)

Upon building the container, I would like to run migrations on the database so that the backend is ready to interact with it.

My two options are

1. Run the migration script in the Database container, when its created
2. Have the application container wait for the DB container to come up and then run the migrations from the application container

Which way would be considered best practice?

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would prefer option 1 when possible, because you avoiding the wait_for command which is basically in other words asking the container every x time if it is ready instead of being notified when its ready.

Honestly it doesn't really matter and you should choose what suite your case the best.

Hope that helps you make a decision.

Best,
Eden